# Finding nearest points to polygon boundaries using QGIS, Points are act as Boundary landmarks

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS, am trying to determine points nearest to the polygons boundary that may act as the last landmarks at the boundary.
There quite many points, households to be precise, but I want only a few as boundary landmarks.
The points  are within the boundaries

Comment: Buffer your polygons and get all points within the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, But I tried buffers , they pick all points within the buffer radius, yet am interested in retaining only a few as landmarks. Also the nearest points to the polygon boundary that are outside the buffer radius will be missed.